# TDS: 'Build fo GetFrameworkPaths failed' after upgrade

Tags: visual-studio, sitecore, tds

I've upgraded my TDS to 5.5 and now I get the following error when opening a solution containing a TDS project with Visual Studio:

```
TDS failed to change configurations with the error 'Build of GetFrameworkPaths failed.'.
Please see the output window for more details.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known issue not yet fixed by Hedgehog. They do provide a workaround:

http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2016/may/common-problem-after-tds-5,-d-,5-upgrade.aspx

To save some time you can just delete the

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\HedgehogDevelopment\SitecoreProject\v9.0\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets

file and run the TDS installer and choose **repair** instead of uninstalling and reinstalling TDS as Hedgehog recommends.

Comment: Tried both the blog post directions and yours, still getting the error. Any other things I could try?

Comment: I suggest to raise the issue with hedgehog support - sorry, no idea beyond that at the moment, got no tds handy.

Comment: This answer also worked for me when getting errors "The target GetFrameworkPaths does not exist in the project" and "The GetProjectContentFiles task was not given a value for the required parameter ConfigurationToBuild" after upgrading to TDS 5.6

Comment: Can confirm this worked for "The GetProjectContentFiles task was not given a value for the required parameter ConfigurationToBuild" on TDS 5.5.

Comment: I experienced this on a fresh install of TDS 6.0. Deleting the targets file and repairing the installation solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error can also appear when running into code / build issues. I saw this error when there was a line ending issue which resulted in a syntax error in my code generation output (eg. Models.cs).

Try these:

- Restart Visual Studio and/or your PC.
- Unload and reload the TDS project(s) with dependencies.
- Restore NuGet packages.
- Check your TDS logs / outputs as there may be a more specific error that precedes this one.
- Inspect your code for any syntax errors / line ending issues.
- Inspect your code for any rule / code quality violations.
- Verify that your other projects can build successfully.